# Redirect URL with parameters

Tags: redirect

I want to use an Arduino to post temperature data to a Google form (which then puts it in a spreadsheet).  The problem is Google forces you to use HTTPS and my Arduino can only support HTTP.  So I'd like to setup a web page that would take the URL parameters and forward them to Google using HTTPS.  For example, the Arduino would do a GET request to a URL like this:

There's actually a lot more parameters.  The "entry.1485604880" is a field ID on the Google form and the number following the = sign is the value for that field.  It's temperature data in my example.  I would need the web page to grab all the field IDs and temperatures and pass them to Google, something like this:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1e_d_kiiKIiDEEredjkdkdfmope893934s/formResponse?entry.1485604880=11&entry.1454471935=12&entry.684946295=13&entry.995372575=14&entry.743946830=15&entry.356028983=16&entry.1065271046=17&entry.697862853=18&entry.185582037=19&entry.1504991118=110

I need help in actually coding the web page and I need suggestions where I can host it, preferably for free.  I don't really know HTML, JavaScript languages, I do know C programming.

Comment: If you like to use advanced communication with arduino I would  recommend Arduino Yun it has a micro linux with libraries to connect to common web services and web sites.

Comment: Also to host a simple web pages you can use **google app engine** or **heroku**. They have a free tier that you can use.